# Simplifying code of a calculator (help)

Tags: c#

This is part of the code of a calculator that works on command line. It works fine and the math is correct but it's a little redundant:

```
switch(Operator)
 {
  case "+": result = num1 + num2;
  printResult();
  break;

  case "-" : result = num1 - num2;
  printResult();
  break;

  case "*":
  result = num1 * num2;
  printResult();
  break;

  case "/":
  result = num1 / num2;
  printResult();
  break;

  case "^":
  result = Math.Pow(num1, num2);
  printResult();
  break;

  case "root":
  result = Math.Pow(num1, (1/num2));
  Console.WriteLine("Root degree " + num2 + " of " + num1 + " is " + result);
  break;

  default:
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid operator.");
  break;

}//END SWITCH
```

Is there a way to avoid this redundant code like

```
result = num1 Operator num2;
```

or

```
for char o = Operator
result = num1 Operator num2;
```

Even just for the + - / * operations ?

Comment: `public static void printResult()
{ 
 
 Console.WriteLine("\n" + calculadora.result); 
}`

Comment: @gnat what do you mean? i'm just a begginer :/

Comment: "you should consider refactoring towards a map based and/or polymorphic solution" (see top answer in duplicate)

Comment: A genuine parser w/ visitor pattern would clean it up (and *quadruple* the LoC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the duplication by moving `PrintResult()` below your switch. You call it every time (nearly, you'll need to make it a touch more robust I imagine). Then, change your method to return a result instead. This method calculates *and* prints. It shouldn't, that break SRP.

Now, you could create a dictionary of functions to be invoked.

```
var operations = new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, double>>()
{
    { "+", (a, b) => a + b },
    { "-", (a, b) => a - b },
    //...
}

return operations[Operator](num1, num2);
```

*May not compile, I'm typing on my phone. Exception handling left to OP.*

Of course, if you get really froggy, [you could go create a calculator parser](https://github.com/ckuhn203/Antlr4Calculator) and really overkill the solution.

Comment: Probably @charlotte. Good call.